# Does anyone know good software for producing tanglegrams?

Tags: bioinformatics, phylogenetics

I'm trying to look at relationships between parasite and host phylogenetic trees. I have done a bit of searching for software with which to do this, and I have tried using Dendroscope and TreeMap, but can't get to grips with them.

I want to produce something along the lines of this;

[image]

Comment: Treemap and Dendroscope are the only ones that I know of. Can you start small? Search for examples like: http://ib.berkeley.edu/courses/ib200b/ib200b_2009/Labs/15%20Biogeography/15%20Biogeography%20and%20Treemap.pdf and try to work through.

Comment: I think that I may have underestimated the complexity of the matter. That run through is very useful, however it is the very earliest stage that I am struggling with. I have two phylogenetic trees (one host and one parasite). Both are in newick format. In this manual it says "This file contains two trees, 
one for the host and one for the parasite, and a description of which hosts are associated 
with which parasites.". I think the lack of description of association is the problem. I assumed the software would take the associations from the information in the trees? I'm not an expert!

Comment: how to use dendroscope3 for making phylogenetic tree?

Comment: The word "software" is uncountable in English so cannot take the indefinite article. I have corrected this in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Dendroscope

Using [Dendroscope](http://ab.inf.uni-tuebingen.de/software/dendroscope/), I opened the provided example file `trees.new`. This opens a new window with 16 trees in it.

1. Shift click on the first two trees (`Tree1` and `Tree2`).
2. Choose `Algorithms` $\rightarrow$ `Tanglegram...`
3. This will compute the tanglegram and open a new window.

At this point, I get:

[image: Tanglegram]

There is nothing special in the `trees.new` file, just 16 Newick trees. So it looks like all you need is to have your trees in the same file or use `File` $\rightarrow$ `Add from file`.

I think that the tricky part is that your trees have to have the same tip labels, so that they can be lined up optimally. So in your example, *Phalacrocorax pygmaeus* and *Pectinopygus excornis* must have been named the same in the original Nexus file and then modified to produce the final figure.

## TreeMap 3

[TreeMap](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~mcharles/software/treemap/treemap3.html) requires some preliminary setup. Basically you create a Nexus file manually. Using the `4taxonmatch` file from the [examples](https://sites.google.com/site/cophylogeny/example-data-files), you can get the basic layout. You have a `HOST` block and a `PARASITE` block. Within each one of those is a `TREE` block, which contains the Newick formatted tree.

The `RANGE` block inside the `DISTRIBUTION` block contains the mapping table. Here `p` maps to `u`, etc. This is the connection between host and parasite.

```
#NEXUS
BEGIN HOST; 
TREE * Host1 = (u, (v, (w, x))); 
ENDBLOCK; 

BEGIN PARASITE;
TREE * Para1 = (p, (q, (r, s))); 
ENDBLOCK; 

BEGIN DISTRIBUTION; 
RANGE 
    p: u, 
    q: v, 
    r: w, 
    s: x
; 
END;
```

In contrast, you get the correctly labelled tree directly. See below.

[image: Tanglegram 2]

Comment: Brillian,it was the tip labels in Dendroscope. I understand how these work now, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I have to confess that I know nothing about phylogenetics and the associated software but according to the abstract of [this article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/zoj.12027/abstract) it seems that they used [BEAST](http://beast.bio.ed.ac.uk/) to map coalescence of co-evolving hosts and parasites.

Also [this article](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/27/13/i248.abstract) is probably of highest interest to you as it compares the efficiency of different software to construct tanglegrams

Comment: That makes two of us! I shall try and use dendoscope again with that article in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can try the R package [dendextend](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/). The function `tanglegram` can do the trick.  Several associated functions are also available for getting plots with minimum entanglements such as `untangle_step_rotate_2side`.

Answer (score 1):

Jane 4 (software for cophylogeny reconcilation) has a tanglegram viewer with an interactive editor.  (https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~hadas/jane/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend mesquite, which I've used to create phylogeny trees with.
There are some intricacies with using it, but there is plenty of documentation on its webpage! 
https://www.mesquiteproject.org/